# Node.js + Angular - Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, puppeteer

I want to create code in Node.js, which uses Puppeteer, and then add this action to `ng-click` in Angular.

So I have Puppeteer code in Node.js:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('/vWniosekurl_form.html', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
      await page.pdf({path: 'images/asd.pdf', format: 'A4'});

      browser.close();
    })();
```

**How can I connect this with the `ng-click` Angular action?**

I wanted try this in my Angular controller:

```
$scope.pupp = function(){
 router.get('/pdf', function(req, res){
  var request = $http.get('/data');    
  request.success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
 });
 request.error(function(data){
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
})};
```

And in my Node.js file app.js:

```
router.get('/pdf', function(req, res){
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('/vWniosekurl_form.html', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
      await page.pdf({path: 'images/asd.pdf', format: 'A4'});

      browser.close();
    })();
});
```

Comment: So I've got in my angular controller something like 
$scope.pupp = function(){
   var request = $http.get('/data');    
    request.success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
    request.error(function(data){
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    })};


and in node: 
router.get('/pdf', function(req, res){ 
MY CODE with puppeteer (in topic) }

Comment: Update your question with this information. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have a look at this question it contains large part of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447247/polymer-starter-kit-with-node-express-and-puppeteer/48475431#48475431

Answer (score 0):

Grab a reference to the `Promise` returned by your anonymous function, and then add a method for when it's resolved:

```
let myPromise = (async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('/vWniosekurl_form.html', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'images/asd.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  browser.close();
})();
myPromise.then(function(){ // do stuff })
```