# Polymer Starter Kit with Node, Express, and Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, polymer, puppeteer

Okay, I'm a newbie to all this so any help greatly appreciated.

I've managed to use Node and Express to serve up Polymer Starter Kit (PSK) website from the Polymer build directory from a file I created in the home directory (server.js):

```
// Node.js notation for importing packages
var express = require('express');

// Spin up a server
var app = express();

// Serve static files from the main build directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build/es5-bundled'));

// Render index.html on the main page, specify the root
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile("index.html", {root: '.'});
});

// Tell the app to listen for requests on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

From the terminal I type 'node server.js' and the website is available on localhost 3000 and all is well.

What I want to do is use a node module, Puppeteer, to generate a PDF file from a sample webpage when the website visitor clicks a button. Here's the code I put into the MyApp class of the my-app.html file of the PSK that is called when a button is clicked.

```
functionPDFCreate() {

  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

  (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.pdf({ path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4' });

    await browser.close();
  })();

}
```

However, the function above returns 'require is not defined'. Am I doing things wrong? Do I need need to somehow put the functionPDFCreate code into server.js and use Express routing? How on earth do I execute the code in functionPDFCreate when a PSK website visitor clicks a button? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Require is only available in nodejs environment, you cannot use it in the browser, unless you use modules like [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Comment: So you can only use require in the server.js file and not in any polymer element? How on earth do I execute the code in the node environment when a PSK website visitor clicks a button from a polymer element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you invoking `functionPDFCreate` in a browser context? It's not going to work even with browserify or webpack as @YouneL suggested.

You should expose endpoint in express app serving your PDF:

```
app.get('/hn', function(req, res) {
    functionPDFCreate().then(() => {
        // now file is written on the disk
        res.sendFile('hn.pdf', { root: '.' });
    });
});
```

`functionPDFCreate` should look like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function functionPDFCreate() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.pdf({ path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4' });

    await browser.close();
}
```

In your browser app, you should have download button like this (framework agnostic example):

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/hn" download="hn.pdf">Download HN PDF</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. In trying the suggestion I realise that the /hn route never gets reached due to the polymer starter kit PRPL pattern - any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: @HalloweenMan It's hard for me to say why this route is not reachable based on your example. I've never worked with a polymer. Can you get pdf by inserting `http://localhost:3000/hn` in browser url bar?

Comment: Initially, yes, but once the homepage is visited and the polymer starter kit PRPL pattern is in browser and cached, it simply defaults to oops 404 not found. I think it's specific to polymer starter kit and app PRPL pattern

Comment: @HalloweenMan since you narrowed problem, you should search for solution or ask a question related only to polymer starter kit (puppeteer part is solved here)